# How do i make a pie radar chart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add a pie radar chart to a Flutter application.

Anyone know how to create pie radar charts?

[image: an example of a radar chart]

I needed exactly like above image.

Anyone know how to create

Comment: You can use a CustomPaint Widget to draw this graph yourself. The math for the angles shouldn't be hard. there are functions in the painting that can draw arcs or pie pieces like you showed. You just need to set the radius and angle based on your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is called polar chart. Yоu can try [Chart JS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/polar-area.html).